# Changing DB Password after installing Acumatica instance

Tags: acumatica

I want to change the SQL DB password after installing Acumatica instance. For instance, want to change the default SQL sa password or just create a new user account for Acumatica. Can I change it? Will Acumatica work after that? What other changes I have to make in order Acumatica to work back again?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credentials used by Acumatica ERP to connect to the database are stored in the `connectionStrings` section of the **web.config** file. You can either update connectionString in web.config manually or use the Acumatica ERP Configuration Wizard (Perform Application Maintenance -> Change Database -> ... -> until you reach the Database Connection step):

[image]

If using the Acumatica ERP Configuration Wizard, as shown in the screenshot above, you have an option to use an existing login from your SQL Server or MySQL database or create a new login right from the configuration wizard.

Comment: That worked, thanks Ruslan. I have tested both the options.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to change the connection string attribute in the 'web.config' file. This is similar to changing any ASP.Net website connection string.

Reference:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752(v=vs.110).aspx

To locate the 'web.config' file on disk you can run IIS Manager 'inetmgr.exe' then right click on the Acumatica website instance in the left tree view and select 'Explore'.

Changing the password is a non destructive operation. If you encounter any issues, you can rollback to the last password. I suggest you also check if 'Acumatica ERP Configuration Wizard' 'Perform Database Maintenance' feature is properly scanning the database entry after the change.